# Unit Testing in ui-router resolve callback

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, jasmine, istanbul

I have been working in a project and i've been using the ui-router plugin.
When I inspect the coverage level of my code, always in the resolve function callback my coverage tool says that my tests never execute the resolve function.

My question:

**How should be testing this code?**

An example of code:

```
$stateProvider
      .state('measures.users', {
        url: 'users',
        views: {
          'navbar': APP_SETTINGS.NAVBAR_SETTINGS,
          'main': {
            templateUrl: 'assets/views/users/users.html',
            controller: 'UsersController',
            controllerAs: 'users',
            resolve: {
              UsersResolve: ['UsersService', function(UsersService){

                  //My coverage tool never pass in here. 
                  //I need testing this area but i dont know what should be test
                  return UsersService.getUsers();
              }]
            }
          }
        }
      })
```

**EDIT**
Finally I testing if my service have been called when i transition to state 'measures.users'.

```
describe('State check', function(){

    var state, rootScope, UsersService;

    beforeEach(module('exampleApp'));
    beforeEach(inject(eachSpecSetup));

    function eachSpecSetup($state, $rootScope, $controller,_UsersService_){
        state = $state;
        UsersService = _UsersService_;
        rootScope = $rootScope;
    }

    it('should be call a UsersService.getUsers to resolve the array to state users', spec1);

    function spec1(){

        spyOn(UsersService, 'getUsers');

        state.go('measures.users');
        rootScope.$digest();

        expect(UsersService.getUsers).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }

});
```

A similar example in [here](http://codepen.io/gpincheiraa/pen/mPaOVY)

Answer (score -1):

Just make sure that :

1. url 'users' is covered in your test;
2. in UsersController, you haved call UsersResolve service.

There may be some syntax errors in your `resolve`:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('measures.users', {
    url: 'users',
    views: {
      'navbar': APP_SETTINGS.NAVBAR_SETTINGS,
      'main': {
        templateUrl: 'assets/views/users/users.html',
        controller: 'UsersController',
        controllerAs: 'users',
        resolve: {
          UsersService: UsersServuce,
          UsersResolve: function(UsersService){
              return UsersService.getUsers();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
```